# Introducing IDs to patches in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo, patch

I am working on a model which is supposed to act like a human tissue. It is composed of only patches which represent the human cells. The cells replicate over time, and I want to introduce unique IDs to each of the individual patches (cells). These IDs should also carry over to the daughter cells after the replication. I cannot seem to find a good starting point for this and not sure how to approach it.

This is the code I tried but it is not working to even at least give each patch a unique ID. Track clones is supposed to give each of the patches an ID and I will later introduce more to the code to track individual patches and their division over time.

```
to track-clones

;  let patch-list patches
;  let patch-count count patches
;  foreach patch-list [
;    set id ?1
; ]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This will have each patch take unique and sequential IDs:

```
to assign-ids
  ask patches [
    set id (max [id] of patches + 1)
  ]
end
```

That said, it is not clear to me what you mean, in model's terms, when you say

> These IDs should also carry over to the daughter cells after the replication.

given that we don't know how such replication is supposed to take place - but it seems this is a separate issue to address.

PS: the syntax using `?` for anonymous procedures is no longer accepted, make sure to check the latest [NetLogo Dictionary](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can quickly assign an initial ID based on the patch coordinates

Ask patches [ set patch-id (pxcor - min-pxcor ) + (pycor - min-pxcor) * world-width
]

Alternately, you can use the patch itself as the patch ID:

Ask patches [ set patch-id self ]

This might make other operations relating to the progenitor patch simpler.